# HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '/test'

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am getting this kind of error when I run jsp file. I have connected using MySQL connector.

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '/test'
>   type Exception report
>
> message javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '/test'
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '/test'
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '/test'
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:908)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:837)
>       org.apache.jsp.reg1_jsp._jspService(reg1_jsp.java:126)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '/test'
>       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4292)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1259)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
>       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>       java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       org.apache.jsp.reg1_jsp._jspService(reg1_jsp.java:107)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 logs.

---

Apache Tomcat/8.0.23

Comment: It clearly says unknown database.post your code.

Comment: The database "test" does not exist. Have you specified the correct MySQL server? Does the database exist there?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your mysql server whether the database name '**test**' is present or not.

If not create and then test.